# Migration / convert an existing site to WordPress

Tags: migration

I have an advertisement site that I create with PHP and MySQL.

The structure of the database is very simple:

- Tables: ads, type of ads, user, and images.
- Each ad has an ad type (offer or request)
- An ad has one or more associated images.
- A user can post multiple ads.

The site contains more than 10 thousand registered ads.

How do I export data to a WordPress database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a custom site and database structure, there is no easy way to import your data into WordPress.

I would suggest you instead focus on how you would accomplish the same thing within WordPress. In other words, start by pretending you don't have those 1,000's of ads, and build out your way of tracking ads in WordPress. Then, when that works, you can think through if there's any way to move some of the data.

If not, it would probably be easier to leave the old ads as-is and have the front-end run both implementations (pull from both data sources).

You *could* build a custom plugin that allowed you to continue using the custom database structure you already have, yet give you an editing capability through WordPress. After all, WordPress is quite comfortable with mySQL.

So consider what you are hoping to gain by integrating the site with WordPress, how you would integrate it with WordPress in the first place, and then whether or not its worth bringing in your old data.

Answer (score 1):

If you can export your existing data into a sensible csv-file, you could perhaps try using one of the many custom import plugins that haven been published for WordPress.

Some of the import plugins allow you to import data from a csv-file as custom post types, custom taxonomies/terms and post meta data to WordPress. But I'm not sure if any of the import plugins are able to handle that much data without grinding your server down.